# Webpage login error-Android App

Tags: java, android, eclipse, html, login-script

I'm new to Android and Java. I'm creating an app to login to my ISP. This is the page: http://reliancebroadband.co.in/reliance/login.do

Earlier, I was using a python script, which worked flawlessly. Its like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import urllib2, urllib, cookielib

username = 'my-username'
password = 'my-password'

jar = cookielib.FileCookieJar("cookies")
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))

response = opener.open("http://reliancebroadband.co.in/reliance/startportal_isg.do")

login_data = urllib.urlencode({'userId' : username, 'password' : password, 'action' : 'doLoginSubmit'})
resp = opener.open('http://reliancebroadband.co.in/reliance/login.do', login_data)
```

And now i'm trying to create an android app(source: http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/login-application-for-android.html#.U7AFBPmSz9Y) (Tried contacting the developer there, but he's not responding.)
The app is compiling correctly, but while tring to login, its just returning the source code of the login page in the error dialogue, instead of logging in.
Here's the code:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.app.reliancebblogin;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
 EditText un, pw;
 TextView error;
 Button ok;
 private String resp;
 private String errorMsg;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  un = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_un);
  pw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pw);
  ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
  error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_error);

  ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
  {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) 
   {
    /** According with the new StrictGuard policy,  running long tasks on the Main UI thread is not possible
    So creating new thread to create and execute http operations */
    new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
     public void run() 
        {
      ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",un.getText().toString()));
      postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pw.getText().toString()));

      String response = null;
      try 
      {
          response = SimpleHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://reliancebroadband.co.in/reliance/login.do", postParameters);
       String res = response.toString();
       resp = res.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

      } 
      catch (Exception e) 
      {
       e.printStackTrace();
       errorMsg = e.getMessage();
      }
     }

    }).start();
    try 
    {
    /** wait a second to get response from server */
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    /** Inside the new thread we cannot update the main thread
    So updating the main thread outside the new thread */

     error.setText(resp);

     if (null != errorMsg && !errorMsg.isEmpty()) 
     {
      error.setText(errorMsg);
     }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
     error.setText(e.getMessage());
    }
   }
  });
 }
}
```

SimpleHttpClient.java:

```
package com.app.reliancebblogin;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParams;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

public class SimpleHttpClient 
{
 /** The time it takes for our client to timeout */
    public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; // milliseconds

    /** Single instance of our HttpClient */
    private static HttpClient mHttpClient;

    /**
     * Get our single instance of our HttpClient object.
     *
     * @return an HttpClient object with connection parameters set
     */
    private static HttpClient getHttpClient() 
    {
        if (mHttpClient == null) 
        {
            mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
            ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        }
        return mHttpClient;
    }

    /**
     * Performs an HTTP Post request to the specified url with the
     * specified parameters.
     *
     * @param url The web address to post the request to
     * @param postParameters The parameters to send via the request
     * @return The result of the request
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static String executeHttpPost(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception 
    {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try 
        {
            HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
            UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
            request.setEntity(formEntity);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();

            String result = sb.toString();
            return result;
        }
        finally 
        {
            if (in != null) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Performs an HTTP GET request to the specified url.
     *
     * @param url The web address to post the request to
     * @return The result of the request
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static String executeHttpGet(String url) throws Exception 
    {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try 
        {
            HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(url));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();

            String result = sb.toString();
            return result;
        }
        finally 
        {
            if (in != null) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your ISP page up, as I tried and it gives time out, so just check once.

Comment: Yes, the site is working. But haven't been able to run the app yet.